# Copying a Subroutine

Tags: perl

I am trying to apply a prototype to a copy of a subroutine, without modifying the existing subroutine. I.e. this is not ok:

```perl
use Scalar::Util 'set_prototype';

sub foo {};
*bar = \&foo;
set_prototype(\&bar, '$');  # also modifes "foo"
```

What I want to achive can be done with a `goto &sub`:

```perl
sub foo {};
sub bar($) {
    goto &foo;
}
```

However, this is introduces unnecessary overhead which I am not keen on. Therefore my question: **Is there a way to make a (shallow) copy of a subroutine (CV), so that setting the prototype of the copy does not affect the original?** I.e. something like

```perl
use Scalar::Util 'set_prototype';

sub foo {};
*bar = magical_cv_copy(\&foo);
set_prototype(\&bar, '$');  # does not modify "foo"
```

I looked at [`Sub:Clone`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub%3a%3aClone), but it appears to be out of date and won't install on my system without forcing it. I would prefer not having to write XS code for this.

#### Test case to clarify my requirements:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 7;
use Scalar::Util qw/refaddr set_prototype/;

sub foo {
    my ($x) = @_;
    return 40 + $x;
}
*bar = then_a_miracle_occurs(\&foo);

ok not(defined prototype \&foo), 'foo has no prototype';
ok not(defined prototype \&bar), 'bar has no prototype';
isnt refaddr(\&foo), refaddr(\&bar), 'foo and bar are distinct';

set_prototype \&bar, '$';

ok not(defined prototype \&foo), 'foo still has no prototype';
is prototype(\&bar), '$', 'bar has the correct prototype';

is foo(2), 42, 'foo has correct behavior';
is bar(2), 42, 'bar has correct behavior';

sub then_a_miracle_occurs {
    my ($cv) = @_;
    # what goes here?
    # return sub { goto &$cv }
}
```

#### In avoidance of the X-Y-Problem:

My *X*-Problem is that a 3rd-party module defines some function `foo` without prototypes. Judicious use of prototypes can make this function more elegant to use, so I want to create a copy of that sub, except that it does have a prototype. I cannot make any assumptions about the `foo` function – it may be also be an XS subroutine.

I cannot directly set the prototype of `foo`, because I do not wish to interfere with other modules that rely on the original behavior of `foo`.

So we arrive at my *Y*-Problem: how to copy a subroutine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The miracle function is probably the internal `cv_clone`.

You mentioned `Sub::Clone`, and it seems to do what you want. It comes with a pure-Perl implementation based on the `goto` trick you described, and an XS implementation that calls `cv_clone`.

I can't find another module that wraps this internal function. If you have trouble installing the module, I'd suggest you open a RT ticket. There's [one older but unresolved ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Sub-Clone) already, so you might have to nudge one of the maintainers.

Ideally, this functionality would be part of a module like `Sub::Util`. We already have `Scalar::Util`, `List::Util`, `Hash::Util`, but nothing for subroutines.

Answer (score 4):

> a 3rd-party module defines some function foo without prototypes. Judicious use of prototypes can make this function more elegant to use, so I want to create copy of that sub, except that it does have a prototype.

All you need is a thin wrapper:

```
sub foo(&@) { &Real::foo }
```

or

```
sub foo(&@) { goto &Real::foo }
```

The difference is that the latter hides the call to your `foo`, which makes a difference if Real::foo checks its caller (e.g. builds a stack trace on error).

If your idea of optimization is getting rid of a sub call, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I addressed that in my question: “*this introduces unnecessary overhead which I am not keen on*”. Specifically, we waste quite a few opcodes on the goto. It is however the solution I've chosen to use in absence of a more elegant way (I have little interest in rummaging through Perl's guts).

Comment: If your idea of optimization is getting rid of a sub call, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: (It's so easy to get lulled into micro-optimizations. Happens to me too all the time)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the Perl code for a sub as a string using [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B%3a%3aDeparse) and then re-`eval` that code to regenerate the sub. If the sub closed over any lexical variables, these can be handled using [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker).

That combination of tricks seems to work for most subs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{
   package Sub::Clone2;
   use PadWalker;
   use B::Deparse;
   use Sub::Identify;

   sub clone_sub
   {
      my ($orig) = @_;
      my $closed_over = PadWalker::closed_over($orig);

      my $orig_pkg = Sub::Identify::stash_name($orig);
      my $orig_code = B::Deparse->new->coderef2text($orig);
      my $decl = join(q[,], sort keys %$closed_over);
      my $clone = eval sprintf('package %s; my(%s); sub %s', $orig_pkg, $decl, $orig_code)
         or die($@);

      PadWalker::set_closed_over($clone, $closed_over);
      return $clone;
   }
}

{
   package Local::Test;

   my $var = 40; # variable to close over

   sub foo {
      my $total = 0;
      $total += ++$var;
      $total += $_ for @_;
      return $total;
   }

   sub reset {
      $var = 40;
   }
}

my $orig   = \&Local::Test::foo;

print "TESTING THE ORIGINAL FUNCTION\n";
print "$_\n"
   for $orig->(1), $orig->(2, 3), $orig->(4, 5, 6);

Local::Test::reset();

my $cloned = Sub::Clone2::clone_sub($orig);

print "TESTING THE CLONED FUNCTION\n";
print "$_\n"
   for $cloned->(1), $cloned->(2, 3), $cloned->(4, 5, 6);

Local::Test::reset();
```

**It won't work for subs that use `our` variables - these will throw an exception saying that the variable has not been declared.** (However, it should work fine for subs that use package variables via their fully-qualified name.)

One possibility would be to use the `clone_sub` technique above, and whenever that throws an exception, fall back to using the `goto` wrapper technique you outlined in the question.

Comment: This is very wonderful code, but unsuitable for my purposes: I do not wish to make *any* assumptions about the sub of which I want to change the prototype. It may be that the original sub is an XS sub, or a sub that uses syntax extensions which cannot be deparsed in any sensible way.

Comment: It may be possible to handle `our` variables using `Devel::Peek` and `B`. I'll make an attempt at that tonight and update this answer if I have any success. For cloning xsubs, I fear that `goto` fakery may be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly unclear on you usage, but :

If you seek to broaden a prototype, then maybe you should simply [prototype the function](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) `foo` correctly in the first place?

If you want to apply additional restrictions, then maybe you should prototype a function that calls the real function `foo`.  Just take note that ["prototypes have no influence on subroutine references"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes), meaning this code fails :

```
*bar = set_prototype(sub { return foo(@_); }, '$');
```

Comment: I am aware of the restrictions around prototypes. You are assuming I have an X-Y-Problem which could be solved by putting the prototype on the original sub in the first place. This is not possible because I am not the author of the original sub, and other modules may rely on the original behavior – hence my wish to make a *copy*. Note that you misunderstood the “*prototypes have no influence on subroutine references*” – your example works just fine, it's just that *calls* like `$coderef->(@args)`, `&$coderef(@args)`, `&subname(@args)` or `$obj->method(@args)` don't check any prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

[*I wasn't sure what the OP could or couldn't do, and turns out this answer is unsuitable. I'd delete it, but it might be useful to someone else, so I'll leave it up.*]

It's hard to tell what you are [trying to accomplish](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Prototypes are apparently applied to the closure and not the underlying components that are shared by all instances of a sub, so forcing the creation of a closure can give you two subs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw( set_prototype );

sub x {
   my $x;
   return sub { $x if 0; print("$_[0]\n"); };
}

my @a = qw( d e f );

BEGIN {
   my $f = x();
   set_prototype(\&$f, '@');
   *f = $f;
}

f(@a);   # d

BEGIN {
   my $g = x();
   set_prototype(\&$g, '$');
   *g = $g;
}

g(@a);   # 3
f(@a);   # d
```

Comment: I made an update to my question regarding the X-Y-Problem. As I have no control over the original sub, I cannot force the creation of a closure. The original may also be an XS function.